# Вывести данный код одним print

Tags: python

День добрый, как можно вывести данный код одним print? Еще если не трудно, то объяснить как это будет работать, я пока только учусь. Код для подсчета символов в слове. Заранее спасибо.

```
word = input()
word = list(sorted(word))
num = 0
num_sim = 1
for sym in word:
    if num+1 < len(word):
        if sym == word[num + 1]:
            num_sim += 1
        else:
            print(num_sim, end=' ')
            print(sym, end=' ')
            num_sim = 1
    else:
        print(num_sim, end=' ')
        print(sym, end=' ')
    num += 1
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

```py
from itertools import groupby

print(*[x for k, g in groupby(sorted(input())) for x in (len(list(g)), k)])
```

либо

```py
from collections import Counter

print(*[x for k, v in Counter(sorted(input())).items() for x in (v, k)])
```

Comment: `print(*[x for k, v in Counter(input()).most_common() for x in (v, k)])` ? ;)

Comment: @MaxU там по алфавиту нужно. Вот еще вариант `print(*map('{0[1]} {0[0]}'.format, Counter(sorted(input())).items()))`

Comment: по алфавиту? я по коду автора вопроса этого не распознал...

Comment: @MaxU Ну по крайней мере авторский код выводит по алфавиту :)